# How to deploy Power Shell Script into a server?

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Push-Location
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-Location C:\
PS C:\> Set-Location HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
PS HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel> Set-ItemProperty . TypeGuessRows "0"
PS HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel>Pop-Location
PS C:\>
```

I am able to run the above commands on my local machine in Power shell command editor.

And looking to deploy into server, need to know the process of implementation?
(should i save it as a .cmd/.bat/.ps1)?

What are the actual steps for the implementation into a server?

Answer (score 1):

Save as .ps1

copy .ps1 file onto server

open up powershell and run `set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned`

Right click on ps1 file, click "Run with PowerShell"

Answer (score 0):

You can use enter-pssession or invoke-command to add registry values to a remote server. see this link as a reference: [Use PowerShell to Create New Registry Keys on Remote Systems](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/10/use-powershell-to-create-new-registry-keys-on-remote-systems.aspx)